# NotEqualTo Validation in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

Is there a NotEqualTo validator in Zend Framework 2? If not; how can we implement a NotEqualTo validator in Zend Framework 2? Or is there any other workarounds?

**Example**
I have a text field having the following attributes
`'onfocus'=>'if(value==\'Name\'){ value=\'\'}'`
`'onblur'=>'if(value==\'\'){ value=\'Name\'}'`

When the user submits the form without entering their name; I have to validate whether the field is having a value of 'Name' and if it has; return an error.

**Note:**
I can't use the placeholder attribute as my client require the placeholder text to disappear on clicking the text field(currently it disappears only when we begin typing).

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html

Comment: @Notuser - thanks for your reference. do you know any already implemented solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just submit with an empty value and validate it isn't empty? The `onfocus/onblur` attributes as far as I can tell are just supplying placeholder text. You could do that using the html5 `placeholder` attribute, which would avoid the custom validator entirely.

Comment: @Crisp - I can't use the placeholder attribute because of its behavior. i.e; the placeholder text just stays the same when we click on the text field. My client require the placeholder text to disappear when the user clicks on text field. So I have to use JavaScript for the same. Hope it clears your doubt. Anyway I shall update it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simple workaround using the Callback validator as follows.

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Callback',
        'options' => array(
            'callback'=>function($value){
                return $value!='Name';
            }),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Details of the Callback Validator can be seen at the following link
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#callback